# Шаблон Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Шаблон Bootstrap. На мониторе разрешением больше 900px - хорошо смотрится, а именно миниатюры записей выводятся в три столбика. Если уменьшить разрешение экрана меньше 900px, то вёрсткой предусмотрено что бы миниатюры уже выводились в два столбика. Проблема в том, что блоки идут не один за другим. Они разбиты по рядам по 3 записи - на одной строчке 2 миниатюры, на второй только одна (нужно тоже 2), на третей снова 2, потом снова одна. Можно ли при помощи CSS подвинуть записи ровно, что бы после трех записей не было пробела?

```html
 <div id="primary-home" class="content-area col-md-12">
 
  <main id="masonry" class="site-main col-md-12" role="main">

  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

   <?php /* Start the Loop */$ink_count = 0; $ink_row_count=0 ?>
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
     if ($ink_count == 0 ) {echo "<div class='row-".$ink_row_count." row'>";}
   ?>
   

    <?php
     /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
      * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
      * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
      */
     get_template_part( 'content', 'home' );
    ?>

   <?php 
    if ($ink_count == 2 )
     {
      echo "</div>";
      $ink_count=0;
      $ink_row_count++;
     }
    else { 
     $ink_count++;
    }
    
    endwhile; 
   ?>
  <?php else : ?>

   <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

  </main><!-- #main -->
  
  <?php inkzine_pagination(); ?>
  
 </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно, уберите `div` с классом `row` и пишите колонки подряд, в таком случае верстка получится гибкой. Примерно так:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12"> блок 1 </div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12"> блок 2 </div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12"> блок 3 </div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12"> блок 4 </div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12"> блок 5 </div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12"> блок 6 </div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12"> блок 7 </div>
```

и так далее

**UPD:**

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'home' );?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: а в каком файле это делать??

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов очень странный вопрос. там где у вас формируется верстка видимо

Comment: там все через PHP формируется, и не понять. Если б через html, то я бы сам сделал.

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов так добавте в вопрос где у вас формируется контент этой страницы

Comment: вставил, и то сомневаюсь что оно

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов оно, сейчас изменю ответ

Comment: Подправил, но нужно еще у пыхеров спросить, правильно ли с точки зрения синтаксиса... с точки зрения логики вырезал не нужное

Comment: Ок. Спасибо большое. Спрошу

Comment: При замене кода выкинуло ошибку: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/allsaleb/public_html/wp-content/themes/inkzine/home.php on line 23

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов, да, там скобка не закрытая, сейчас подправлю

Comment: Никто по поводу проверки кода так и не ответил, но всё работает! Спасибо большое тебе, PHP мастер!

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов я с PHP не работаю, но галочку свою в карму получить готов ;)

Comment: Я тут новичок, куда нужно нажать?

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов на против ответа слева есть стрелочки, нужно нажать на стрелку вверх и на галочку под стрелками

Comment: Мне пишет - нужно 15 балов репутации, что бы нажимать на стрелку. Тут есть что то типа друзей? Что бы я потом мог тебе нажать.

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов забей, успеешь еще нажать за другие ответы :)

Comment: Я помню тебя, друг!

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов :)

Answer (score 0):

У вас там все картинки по divам раскинуты при помоши css это можно сделать только если нарушить адаптивность при помоши позицианирования. Легче все таки с html или со скриптом разбираться.

Comment: Это тут?`if(!jQuery)throw new Error("Bootstrap requires jQuery");+function(a){"use strict";function b(){var a=document.createElement("bootstrap"),b={Web...`
Я просто не разбираюсь в скриптах